# Trying to read from a file and count the number of phrases that match words in an array

Tags: java, file, while-loop, io

I am trying to read a file that is given by the user.  The program should scan the file and count the number of words in the document that match words that I have listed in an array.  When I run my program, it is getting stuck in my while loop and I am not sure why it is happening.  Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

```
package pkgfinal.nhammer2;


import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FinalNhammer2 {

    // Phishing Phrases
    private static final String[] phishingPhrases = {"label", "invoice", "post",
        "document", "postal", "calculations", "copy", "fedex", "statement",
        "financial", "dhl", "usps", "8", "notification", "n", "irs", "ups", 
        "no", "delivery", "ticket", "express", "shipment", "international",
        "parcel", "confirmation", "alert", "report", "idnotification", "shipping",
        "ssn"
    };

    private static final int phrasePoints[] = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,
        2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = 0;
        int numberOfPhrases = 30;

        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        Path path = Paths.get(file.nextLine());

        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            System.out.printf("%n%s exists%n", path.getFileName());
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhrases; i++){
                while(file.hasNext()){
                    String word = file.next();
                    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(phishingPhrases[i])){
                        count++;
                    }                    
                }
            }

            System.out.printf("File has %d phishing phrases", count);
        }

        else{
            System.out.printf("%s does not exist.", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address the following problems in your code:

1. Create a new `Scanner` for the file.
2. Swap the sequence of loops.

Do it as follows:

```
int count = 0;
int numberOfPhrases = 30;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
String fileName = in.nextLine();

File fileObj = new File(fileName);
if (fileObj.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File exists");
    Scanner file = new Scanner(fileObj);

    while (file.hasNext()) {
        String word = file.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < phishingPhrases.length; i++) {
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(phishingPhrases[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();
    System.out.printf("File has %d phishing phrases", count);
} else {
    System.out.println("File does not exist");
}
```

Comment: do I need to use a different import for File fileObj = new file(fileName); to work?

Comment: import `java.io.File`

Comment: I am getting an error on the line

Scanner file = new Scanner(fileObj);

the error says "unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or decalred to be thrown"

Comment: Ah...just add `throws FileNotFoundException` in the declaration of `main` i.e. `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.